# Running a batch of tests in a suite

Tags: watir-webdriver

Back when my test library was running on Watir 2.0.4/Ruby 1.8.7 I was able to use test/unit/testsuite to run a batch of tests in a suite that could run a defined list of test concurrently (see below):

```
require 'test/unit/testsuite'
require 'test/unit/ui/console/testrunner'
```

`require 'foo1.rb'
require 'foo2.rb'

class Foo
    def self.suite
        suite = Test::Unit::TestSuite.new(Foo)

        suite << foo1.suite
        suite << foo2.suite

        return suite
    end
end
Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner.run(Foo)<code>`

Now I’m using Watir-webdriver on Ruby 1.9.2, this doesn’t seem to work:

> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file >to load -- test/unit/testsuite (LoadError)
>     from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
>     from testsuite.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
>     from -e:1:in`load'
>     from -e:1:in `'

What are other people doing to string a batch of tests in a suite?

Thanks,

GJHmf

Comment: Are you actually using the `test-unit` gem (ie you manually installed this) or are you using the new `minitest` gem?

Comment: I've not tried the new minitest gem yet, but it's actually quite embarrassing that I've just spotted that I didn't have test-unit installed at all. I was postive it was in my gem list; but I guess I missed that when I upgraded my environment.  Thanks for the nudge in the right direction, my old test suites now work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that this question has an answer, as mentioned in the comments, the problem was that the test-unit gem was not installed.

The test-unit gem used to be included in the default installation of Ruby 1.8.7. In Ruby 1.9, it was replaced by the minitest gem, which is why you now have to manually install it.

To use the same version of test-unit that was in Ruby 1.8.7:

```
gem install test-unit -v 1.2.3
```

Or the latest version:

```
gem install test-unit
```